# How do I use .take on FirebaseListObservable?

Tags: rxjs, angularfire2

If I try to use RxJS operators like .take, .skip, etc. on FireBaseListObservable, I get "take is not a function" error:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {AngularFire, FirebaseListObservable} from 'angularfire2';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';

export class AppComponent {
  items: FirebaseListObservable<any>;

  constructor(public af: AngularFire) {
    // this works
    Observable.interval(1000).take(5).subscribe(x => console.log(x));

    this.items = af.database.list('/items');
    // this does not
    this.items.take(1).subscribe();
  }
}
```

Edit:
importing .take via import "rxjs/add/operator/take"; did work, though now I have another question:

Why

```
Observable.interval(1000).take(5).subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

works even without importing the take?

And how do I cast Observable to FirebaseListObservable?

Comment: Can you include the `import` statement you used for `Observable`?

Comment: I've updated the answer with an example cast (and with the reason I mentioned it). In using `import {Observable} from 'rxjs';` you've imported RxJs in its entirety. I don't have an explanation for why this wouldn't result in `take` (and all of the other operators) being available on the AngularFire2 observables. It's a mystery. To get to the bottom of it you'd need to include all of the `import` statements and versions, etc. If I use that import, I get all of the operators.

Comment: @cartant: all imports are included now

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the problem with angularfire2 2.0.0-beta.5 and rxjs 5.0.0-beta.12. Importing `Observable` the way you are gets me all of the operators. Your error is a TypeScript error and not a runtime error, right?

Comment: My error is a runtime error:
zone.js:390Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in ./AppComponent class AppComponent_Host - inline template:0:0 caused by: this.items.take is not a function(…)I'm using beta.6 though

Comment: I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RxJS is distributed in a manner that allows it to be imported in its entirety or in small pieces.

For the `take` operator and its TypeScript declarations to be included, you could choose to either import RxJS in its entirety:

```
import * as Rx from "rxjs/Rx";
```

Or could import only the `take` operator that you require:

```
import "rxjs/add/operator/take";
```

Note that the AngularFire2 observables implement [`lift`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJS/issues/60) for composition with operators. The effect of this is that after you use an operator, the type will be `Observable<T>` rather than `FirebaseListObservable<T>`, so if you are assigning the composed observable to a `FirebaseListObservable<T>` variable or property you will need a cast.

For example:

```
let item = af.database.list('/items').take(1) as FirebaseListObservable<any>;
```

However, you would only need to do so if you intended to use the variable as a `FirebaseListObservable` (it has additional methods). Typically, you'd leave it as an `Observable`. (I mentioned this as you had a property with the type `FirebaseListObservable<any>` and I've seen this cause confusion in a number of other questions.)

In relation to the errors you've mentioned in comments made against the question, the interplay between imports matters. If you are importing `Observable` like this:

```
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
```

You will be including RxJS in its entirety and all of the operators should be available when composing `FirebaseListObservable` instances.

However, the if the imported `Observable` is *not used anywhere* in the module into which it is imported, it's *ignored*, and you won't get anything imported. Which is likely why you need the explicit import for `take`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have more questions now ;) See edits.