# Is there a flatMap equivalent which returns the inner observable?

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, rxjs, angularfire

I'm using AngularFire2 and I'm doing something like this:

```
// assume loggedInUserId is Observable<string>
var firebaseList = loggedInUserId
   .flatMap((userId) => this.db.list(this.firebaseRoot.child(userId)))
```

`this.db.list` returns a `FirebaseListObservable<any[]>` with handy functions like `push`, `delete`, etc. but `flatMap` only returns `Observable<any[]>` so I don't get access to them.

Is there an equivalent to `flatMap` that would return the `FirebaseListObservable`? Or is that impossible?

Comment: It's impossible. See my comments in [this](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/1008#issuecomment-304510732) AngularFire2 issue for an explanation. Please feel free to adapt the comments and [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try use map instead, it'll retain the original observable from firebase

> Edited: maybe casting is the answer

```
var firebaseList = loggedInUserId.flatMap((userId) => 
this.db.list(this.firebaseRoot.child(userId)))  as FirebaseListObservable<any>
firebaseList.flatMap(items=>ob.push({foo:'bar'})).subscribe()
```

For change to the right typing please see this
[How do I use .take on FirebaseListObservable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40621006/how-do-i-use-take-on-firebaselistobservable)

Comment: True, but then I've got an `Observable` of `Observable`s which means I need to do `x | async | async` and all sorts of other weirdness. I'll look into that link though - I might be able to cast it with `as`...

Comment: Ya you are right, maybe  cast and flatten it with flatmap will work

Comment: I'm afraid not :/ casting with `as` and logging in the console still results in an `Observable`.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```
loggedInUserId.subscribe(userId => { 
  var firebaseList = this.db.list(this.firebaseRoot.child(userId))
  // do stuff with the list
}
```

***Edit***

Does switchMap return the type you need?

```
const firebaseList = 
  loggedInUserId.switchMap( userId => 
    this.db.list(this.firebaseRoot.child(userId))
  )
```

Comment: Yeah I looked at that approach, but I've got class methods which use the Firebase functions, and I'd rather keep them simple and synchronous rather than using `subscribe` every time.

Comment: So, then Fan's suggestion to use `map()` (where I've used subscribe) should do it. I understand that `return OuterObservable.someOperator(outerVal => { return InnerObservable...})` pattern will return the type of the inner. You pretty much have that, so maybe the operator is incorrect. I'll check the theory out.

Comment: No luck on switchMap - VS code tells me it's `(local var) test: Observable<any[]>`. I think @cartant's comment might be the answer.

Comment: Indeed, I found that out too.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a converter

```
const mapToFirebaseListObservable = (source) => {
  new FirebaseListObservable(observer => {
    return source.subscribe({
      next(x) { observer.next(x); },
      error(err) { observer.error(err); },
      complete() { observer.complete(); }
    })
  })
}
```

Use it with

```
var firebaseList = mapToFirebaseListObservable(
  loggedInUserId
    .flatMap((userId) => this.db.list(this.firebaseRoot.child(userId)))
)
```

I haven't tried it out on a full firebase install, so you may get an error newing up FirebaseListObservable, but I have tried it with an Observable with an added function

```
const newObservable = new Observable(observer => {
  ...
})
newObservable['myFn'] = () => 'from myFn'
```

and the function is present and callable on the output.

**EDIT: This also appears to work**

```
const toInner = (source) => {
  return source.operator && source.operator.project
    ? source.operator.project()
    : source
}
```

Usage:

```
var firebaseList = toInner(
  loggedInUserId
    .flatMap((userId) => this.db.list(this.firebaseRoot.child(userId)))
)
```

It could also be turned into a chained operator

```
const toInner = function() {
  const source = this
  return source.operator && source.operator.project
    ? source.operator.project()
    : source
}
Observable.prototype.toInner = toInner;
```

See also [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/5dbad94e25d24b7a2ae5b77d2b73b26b51435a53/doc/lettable-operators.md#build-your-own-operators-easily) for Rxjs v5.50beta about changes to creating operators.